# A List became empty without modifying it in java

Tags: java, list

Currently, I'm getting stuck with what it seems to be an unexpected error.
I'm programming with the java language, using eclipse as IDE.

The List in question is declared as follows :

```
private final List<Integer> resList;
```

Using the "Watchpoint" feature of `eclipse` while debugging the program, I've seen the following process :
After returning the `resList` List two times, and before returning it for the third time, the List became suddenly empty.

If anyone have a suggestion to give me in order to fix that problem, I would be very pleased ?

Concerning the code, I posted all the methods that access the resList list and are invoked in the program :

Here is the first One :

```
public CloudInformationService(String name) throws Exception {
        super(name);
        resList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        arList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        gisList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
```

And the second one :

```
public void processEvent(SimEvent ev) {
        int id = -1;  // requester id
        switch (ev.getTag()) {
                ...
                    // A resource is requesting to register.
            case CloudSimTags.REGISTER_RESOURCE:
            resList.add((Integer) ev.getData());
            break;
                ...
            }
    }
```

And finally, The third one :

```
private static CloudInformationService cis;
    public static List<Integer> getCloudResourceList() {
        if (cis == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return cis.getList();// The implementation of this method is listed below
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
            return resList;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some code please?

Comment: your declaration seems fine, but where is your initialization? Can you provide some code?

Comment: could you post the method, which returns the list, or other parts of your code that might have access to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: use ctrl+alt+H to look up references to resList and look for methods calling remove, clear, removeAll. If there are too many methods using resList move on to Step 2.

Step 2: Set breakpoints in the CloudInformationServices constructor, when hit, set up breakpoints in LinkedList/AbstractList (in the JDK) in all remove, clear, removeAll methods. In the breakpoints view, right click on resList and choose instance breakpoints. Pick all your remove, clear, removeAll breakpoints and continue execution. Now you'll get a breakpoint hit and can observe from where the list is being emptied.

Without any more code there isn't much help you can get I'm afraid.